# How can I replace a character in a specific JSON field?

Tags: json, awk, sed

If I have a file with such content:

```
{"id":"doi-platelemetry-doi/doiplatelemetry","name":"doi/doiplatelemetry","location":"doi/doiplatelemetry/2.0.0/doiplatelemetry:2.0.0_49","component":"doi","tag":"2.0.0_49"},{"id":"doi-maintenance-service-doi/maintenance-service","name":"doi/maintenance-service","location":"doi/1.0.0/maintenance-service:1.0.0.681","component":"doi","tag":"1.0.0.681"}
```

How do we replace all `/` with `-` only in the value of location field? Meaning, after the replacement, the file content should be:

```
{"id":"doi-platelemetry-doi/doiplatelemetry","name":"doi/doiplatelemetry","location":"doi-doiplatelemetry-2.0.0-doiplatelemetry:2.0.0_49","component":"doi","tag":"2.0.0_49"},{"id":"doi-maintenance-service-doi/maintenance-service","name":"doi/maintenance-service","location":"doi-1.0.0-maintenance-service:1.0.0.681","component":"doi","tag":"1.0.0.681"}
```

This can be very easily achieved using `jq` but I am looking for a solution that works even when tools like `jq` are not available.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Do not try to modify JSON as if it is just a bunch of characters. JSON is a structured format, and treating it as if it's just lines of data is going to cause you sorrow.  Use a tool like `jq` to properly manipulate JSON.

Comment: Yes, I could see expected output using ```jq```. Was just thinking if we can achieve the same without extra tools. What I had pasted in the question was just a small part of the entire document thinking there must be solution without ```jq```. On my original json document, this works perfectly fine: ```cat images.json | jq '.payload[].location |= "gsub("/";"-")' > images.json_modified```

Comment: `jq` is the right tool for the job. Anything you try without `jq` is going to be prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { RS=","} /location/ { gsub("/","-",$0) } {ORS=","}1' file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file
```

Set the record separator to "," and then when the record contains location, using gsub to replace all "/" for "-"

Comment: This splits the records and then makes the modification. This is not making the changes to the file so that we get the final output.

Comment: No worries. I've amended the solution to output to a temp file and copy the tmp file to the master.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit in my earlier comment. Redirecting to a temp file and then renaming it to original is well understood. But what goes into that temp file is not the JSON document but records splitted.

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to set the output record separator. Try it now.

Comment: ```{"id":"doi-platelemetry-doi/doiplatelemetry"
"name":"doi/doiplatelemetry"
"location":"doi-doiplatelemetry-2.0.0-doiplatelemetry:2.0.0_49","component":"doi","tag":"2.0.0_49"},{"id":"doi-maintenance-service-doi/maintenance-service","name":"doi/maintenance-service","location":"doi-1.0.0-maintenance-service:1.0.0.681","component":"doi","tag":"1.0.0.681"}
,``` This is the output that is produced. These are all different lines and no longer a valid JSON. Based on your solution, I will try to give it a shot to see if I can make it work.

Comment: This is why you don't want to treat JSON as if it's just characters.  Also, this answer does not take into account your requirement of "only in the location field".  Use a tool like `jq`.

Comment: OK, try the amended the solution

Comment: Try the solution now.